# Cant read values from Json file after publishing

Tags: json, .net-core, .net-core-configuration

I can read values (value1,Value2) while development, Cant read them after publishing what maybe the problem?

```
public  IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    }

public void readValues()
    {
        var val1 = ($"{Configuration["Value1"]}");
        var val2 = ($"{Configuration["Value2"]}");
    }
```

Json:

```
    {
       "Value1": "Hello",
       "Value2": "World"
    }
```

Comment: Can you please check the ContentRootPath and make sure that location has required permissions. It seems more likely path and permission issue.

Comment: what you mean saying `Cant read them after publishing`. Do you have an exception? Have you checked that an `appsettings.json` file exists in publish folder?

Comment: val1 and val2 while development i can read there values, after publishing the app reads the file but the values(Value1,Value2) are giving an empty string @Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructor that you added to this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

This will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your publish job isn't copying the `appsettings.json` to the publish folder?

You can confirm that by checking the contents of the directory you app was published to. 
Are you publishing with .NET Core CLI? Like: `dotnet publish -c Release`?

What version are you targeting? In case it's netcoreapp2.0, for example:
The publish path goes by `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish`.
You should be able to find `appsettings.json` there.

If it's not there you can set fix it by changing the project file (csproj):

```
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If that's not the problem and the file is in fact in the publish directory, it might be the directory where you are invoking the program is not the publish directory and in runtime the code doesn't find `appsettings.json`

If none of those help you, please provide more context like share the project and details on how you are running the published version.

Comment: It seems that the problem isn't in the json file, its running locally. The problem seems that when Uploading them to a docker image it search for the appsettings.json file while building up the image. `sudo docker run --net=my_bridge -it --name test-app -v/var/test:/var/test microsoft/aspnetcore-build /bin/bash -c "dotnet /var/test/test.dll"`

Comment: your Dockerfile has to have a COPY of the contents of the published folder over to the image. if your dll is under /var/test/test.dll, the ENTRYPOINT should be set to /var/test